# 小学生读小学，中学生读中学，大学生读大学，研究生读什么？

Tags: word-choice

在中文中，我们通常说：

> 小学生**读**小学。
> 中学生**读**中学。
> 大学生**读**大学。

这些句子描述学生的学习阶段。

（老实说，我不知道怎么用英文表达这些句子。在这个语境中，[Assistant](https://poe.com/Assistant)把“读”翻译成“to attend”，但是我认为这个英文单词，意思和参加、出席更近。说不定，英文中没有这个概念，不能直接地翻译。）

以上三个例句我能理解，不过进一步考虑后，我被以下的问题难住了：

**题**：小学生读小学，中学生读中学，大学生读大学，研究生读什么？

通过[百度](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E7%94%9F%E8%AF%BB%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88)和[谷歌](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E7%94%9F%E8%AF%BB%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88)的搜索，我没有找到答案，网页一般讨论研究生的专业等。

Comment: To nitpick on your otherwise stellar grammar: 愣住 is usually intransitive, so "×我被以下的问题愣住了" is ungrammatical (although understandable).  The word to use here is 难住, as in 我被以下的问题难住了.

Comment: Hey thanks!  I edited it in.  (I learned a new word and grammar point today.)

Comment: As for an English equivalent, I would probably use _go to_, or rephrase with _is a X student_. The actual sentences given are of course entirely tautologous, and they sound sillier in English than in Chinese (‘primary school students go to primary school’… well, duh – or even worse, ‘primary school students are primary school students’, a truism if ever I saw one).

Answer (score 2):

小学生读小学。- Grade students study in grade school. (grades 1-6)

中学生读中学。- High/Junior High schoolers study in high school/junior high school. (junior HS - grades 7-9; HS - grades 10-12)

大学生读大学。- Collegiates/Undergraduates study in college/university.

研究生读研究所(台灣) - Graduate students study in graduate school.

Answer (score 2):

研究生大部分也是在大学里读,小部分去研究所或者研究院读。

研究生在大学、研究所或者研究院里读研。

Answer (score 1):

**答**：研究生**读研**

研究生 can mean both "graduate school" and "graduate student".

However, the phrase "读研究生" is commonly abbreviated as "读研".

例句一：如今已经快研究生毕业，**读研**后才发现自己真的不爱学习。[来源](https://www.zhihu.com/question/27605636)

例句二：为什么要**读研究生**？[来源](https://www.zhihu.com/question/21805032)

例句三：很多研究生，**读研**三年过得似乎并不开心。[来源](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/125595546)

又见 [“学历”](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AD%A6%E5%8E%86/5945499)

Answer (score 1):

这个问题涉及了（整体）教育阶段的划分与高等教育内部阶段的划分，而这二者有所不同，所以问题才会显得奇怪。同样的问题在英语中也存在，但似乎不那么明显。原问题可以近似地用英语这么问：

Primary school students study at primary schools. Secondary school students study at secondary schools. University (/undergraduate) students study at universities. Where do master (/graduate) students study?

“大学生”这个词的词义基本等价于“本科生”。习惯上，“本科生”一词基本仅在讨论或考虑后续的高等教育阶段时（即硕士研究生和博士研究生时）才会使用；而在其他情况下基本都会使用“大学生”一词。而“研究生”则一般泛指本科之后的高等教育阶段，同时涵盖硕士研究生和博士研究生；有时偏义指向硕士研究生。但无论是本科生还是硕士生或博士生，他们学习的场所都是大学，即高等教育的场所。

“小学生”和“中学生”这两个词完全不涉及高等教育内部的划分，所以在其后使用“大学生”一词很顺畅，但如果再并列“研究生”则有点奇怪。类似地，如果将原问题中的“大学生”改成“本科生”，则在读到这里时就会感觉奇怪。而原问题正是在这样有点奇怪（语义不连贯）的地方下手，将其放大。

当然往深一步追究，该问题也涉及了为什么小学、中学、大学、本科、专科、学士、硕士、博士被这样称呼的问题。这就是另一个话题了，如果展开就太长了，还会涉及一些翻译与历史话题。

Answer (score 0):

研究生读研究生院，Or 研究生学院。

研究生院 or 研究生学院 in English is commonly referred to as "Graduate School" or "Graduate College." It is an educational institution or department within a university that offers advanced academic programs beyond the undergraduate level. In a graduate school, students pursue master's degrees, doctoral degrees (Ph.D.), and sometimes other specialized postgraduate degrees or certificates.

Answer (score 0):

In U.K. it can be translated as:
Primary school students go to primary schools
Secondary school students go to secondary schools
University students go to universities
Where do PHD students go?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language StackExchange, and thanks for your contribution. Please note that the OP is not asking for translation of the title of the question, but something more specific as manifested in the description.

Answer (score 0):

In 小学生读小学, 读 is a verb but the second 小学 is not its object, but a adverb, just as in the English sentence “I go home”. The sentence is actually 小学生在小学里读书。Interestingly, we can also say 小学生在小学里学习, but we do not say 小学生学小学. We have to be specific with 学, such as 小学生学拼音，学算术。

Another similar situation is 高中毕业生考大学，meaning attaining the college enrollment examination, but not to examining the college.